# SSL Cert Client Validation - How to?

Tags: shell, unix, ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

We're setting up a VIP using F5 load balancer in Windows 2008 Server. My IT dept has setup this VPI URL https://mydomain.com & I need to test below scenarios but not sure how to do it?

```
SSL termination should happen for all requests.
Should reject/drop the request if client SSL does not match.
Forward the request to my application, if client SSL matches.
```

Badically, the certificate is configured on Load balancer in such a way that LB will reject the request if client SSL does not match & it'll accept it only if client SSL matches.

Can any one tell me how to test this using some shell script or other way?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as "an SSL". Are you talking about SSL/TLS client certificates?

Comment: yes, I'm referring to SSL/TLS certs. Any script to verify that if client cert does not match, LB should reject request.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't match"?

Comment: client will talk to LB & if client cert matches with LB cert, then only LB needs to accept the request, all other requests should be rejected by LB. How should I test this LB setting? Any shell script that will act as client & try to access LB, donno how to write this test script?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [openssl s_client](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
$ curl --cert bogus_cert.pem https://mydomain.com
```

Comment: If I have a .crt file, can I use like $ curl --cert bogus_cert.crt https://mydomain.com? Is this .pem file a CAfile?

Comment: @Mike: `--cert` specifies client certificate. `--capath`, `--cacert` -- for CA. [Read the link I've provided above](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: So, if I specify $ curl --capath abc.crt https://mydomain.com, would that work?

Comment: @Mike: the file should be in pem format as the docs that I've linked say.